# Mysql database schema for synonymous and antonymous database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I would like to create a database for synonymous and antonymous, but im not sure how to make the relationships between tables for better performance and also which index should i create.

First i thought:

```
table name: synonymous
id (int) primary key
name (varchar) text index
syn_group_id (int)
ant_group_id (int)
```

So all the synonymous will have the same syn_group_id but this is not possible as all the words dont share the same synonymous, same happens for antonymous. So im totally lost on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would image you could simply have a structure like this:

```
table: Words
id(int, autoindex,primary,key)
word(varchar, unique index)

table: Synonyms
lookup_id, related_id (both int related to words table id field with compound primary key indexing)

table: Antonyms (same structure as synonyms)
```

The synonyms and antonyms tables are simply just many-to-many join tables related to the words table.

So a sample lookup query could be:

```
SELECT w.word FROM words as w INNER JOIN synonyms as s on w.id = s.related_id WHERE s.lookup_id = [LOOKUP_ID];
```

Comment: It makes sense but if for example i would like to retrieve all syns of a word with id = 3 the query should be "SELECT word FROM words, synonyms WHERE words.id =  synonyms.id2 AND synonyms.id1 = 3"  ? That query its optimized?